# Images not showing after wordpres update 5.6

Tags: images, thumbnails

```
<img data-original="This image is never shown" src="This image is always visible" class="lazy img-responsive" alt="Alt">
```

After wordpress update lazy load not working. Image paths at attribute data-original are valid but never shown.

Comment: That's not WordPress's built-in lazy loading mechanism, which uses `loading="lazy"`. What are you using to do the lazy loading - a plugin, a script in your theme? Which script?

Comment: @Rup jquery.lazyload

Comment: OK - is that compatible with jQuery 3.x? WordPress 5.6 changed the jQuery version from 1.12 to 3.5.1, and I think it has dripped the jQuery compat script too. So I'd guess your lazyload script is not compatible with newer jQuery.

Comment: Yeah. Jquery was problem. Iv downgraded jquery version. Now its working. Thanks @Rup

Comment: Great, but the correct solution would be to get a version of jquery.lazyload that works with the new jQuery, WordPress is going to keep using jQuery 3+ and at some point other plugins might start relying on the new version.